# phonegap geo location not working

Tags: cordova, geolocation

I am trying to display the location of the user via googles geo location api 
its working fine for 2g connection but not working with 3g or 4g connectionn.
neither the success function nor the error function is called

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    input{width:100%;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:18px;
    padding:6% 0;
    }
        </style>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
           <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
function codeLatLng(){
var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
  var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 1;

     if(states[networkState]!=1)
     {

     var x=document.getElementById("myHeader");
     x.innerHTML="Fetching your location";
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess);
     }
     else{
        // alert("please check ur internet connection");
         var x=document.getElementById("myHeader");
     x.innerHTML="No internet connection";
     }

 function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

function onSuccess(position)
  {

     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      var lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var lng = position.coords.longitude;

   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
   geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
       var x=document.getElementById("myHeader");
    x.innerHTML=results[1].formatted_address;
   });
  }

}
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
         <div id="panel">

      <input type="button" value="Show my location" onclick="codeLatLng()">
      <h1 id="myHeader">your location</h1>
    </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>

enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got it worked by adding

```
{ enableHighAccuracy: true }
```

thank u all :)